# Pandas Data Frame how to merge columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like in the picture. How can I turn it into the table like below. (the demonstration is in excel but I just want to illustrate to you how the table look like- this question does not related to importing and exporting dataframe from/to excel)

Thank you [image]

Comment: This is unclear. In `pandas` itself, you don't get these "combined cells" as you visualize them. You can't, as far as I know, get your output into Excel with combined rows *from* `pandas` in the way you want. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I just wonder is there anyway to display the pandas dataframe like the second table (the below table). I do not want to extract the table to excel or load the table from excel either. I just wonder whether we can display "combined cells" like the below table simply with pandas command

Comment: @PhuongDuyenHuynhNgoc No, pandas isn't a visualisation library so it doesn't make sense to ask to to display a table in a non standard way. In what context do you want to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible.

Underlying `pandas.DataFrame` objects are `numpy` arrays, which do not group data in the way you suggest. Therefore, an arbitrary column cannot be displayed as grouped data.

**Option 1**

It is possible to *partially* replicate your desired output by using MultiIndex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['AAA', 8, 2, 'BBB'],
                   ['AAA', 9, 5, 'BBB'],
                   ['AAA', 10, 6, 'BBB']],
                  columns=['Name', 'Score1', 'Score2', 'PM'])

res = df.set_index(['Name', 'PM'])
```

Result:

```
          Score1  Score2
Name PM                 
AAA  BBB       8       2
     BBB       9       5
     BBB      10       6
```

**Option 2**

Or you can add a dummy column and `set_index` on 3 columns:

```
df['dummy'] = 0
res = df.set_index(['Name', 'PM', 'dummy'])
```

Result:

```
                Score1  Score2
Name PM  dummy                
AAA  BBB 0           8       2
         0           9       5
         0          10       6
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it is what I am looking for.

Comment: What does the dummy column in the option 2 used for? I don't see much difference compared with option 1, except that a new dummy column is added in option 2.

Comment: @ollydbg23, OP is interested in *visual representation* (as misguided as that is for Pandas). Visually, the BBB is repeated in option 1, not in option 2.

Comment: @jpp, Thanks for the reply, indeed, I did not notice the difference of column "PM" in the two options.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe you have looks fine. It really depends on what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to return a dataframe where Name is AAA and PM is BBB you should use the pandas lookup

```
dfnew = df[(df.Name == 'AAA') & (df.PM == 'BBB')]
```

Comment: Hi, Ithank you for your answer, but I think you have misunderstood what I mean, I mean how can I turn from the table above to the table below. Because the column name and PM is the same, so I want to merge them into one single value