# How to output html table with merged cells from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame df as:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,2,2,3], [1,2,3,3,3],[1,3,2,3,5],[7,9,9,3,2]], columns=list("ABCDE"))
```

[image: dataframe presented as table]

I want to achieve this type of table in html (with control of which cells I can merge)
[image: dataframe presented as table after merge]

I know that it can be achieved manipulating the table obtained from df.to_html() function and using jquery to expand the rowspans, yet **I'm asking about the pythonic way** to do it, i.e. is there a possible way of obtaining the merged table directly from some sort of pivot table / dataframe.

I thought about temporary setting the columns to merge as indexes in multi indexed data frame, however this approach is.. crude, to say the least.

It would be perfect if I had the full control of which cells can I merge, based on, for example, values of other cells in the same row.

Comment: I can't think of any obvious way to do this. If you run `df.set_index(list('ABCDE')).to_html('test.html')`, you'll see that merging does exist for index cells (but only in cases where everything to the left matches too). I mention this not because it solves your problem, but maybe if you want to take a look into the `to_html` [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/01babb590cb15ef5c6e9ad890ea580a5112e6999/pandas/io/formats/html.py), you can find the code that is responsible for this merging of similar cells in the index output and you can tweak it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: I've managed to find [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533330/pandas-data-frame-how-to-merge-columns), with extensive answer (see **jpp**'s answer), yet unfortunately negating possibility of simple solution to my problem. As [silkworm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6866811/thesilkworm) suggested, for now the only possibility is to delve the `to_html` source, or meddling with multi indexing the dataframe.