# How to include a text summary within a printed table?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes:

```
data1 = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'Height': [165, 182, 177]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    'Summary': ["Alice is the youngest", "Bob is the tallest"]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Is there a way I could vertically concatenate the two dfs in such a way:

```
+---+---------+-----+----------+
|   |   Name  | Age |  Height  |
+---+---------+-----+----------+
| 0 |  Alice  |  25 |    165   |
| 1 |   Bob   |  30 |    182   |
| 2 | Charlie |  35 |    177   |
+---+---------+-----+----------+
|   |          Summary         |
+---+--------------------------+
| 0 | "Alice is the youngest"  |
| 1 |   "Bob is the tallest"   |
+---+--------------------------+
```

Everything I have attempted so far either groups all fours columns together at the top.

Comment: Possibly relevant post https://stackoverflow.com/q/49533330/1328439

Comment: And another related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57217927/1328439. Here the conclusion was to output html and then transform the resulting HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) and post-process the outputs:

```
import tabulate as t

t.PRESERVE_WHITESPACE = True

width1 = 10
width2 = width1 * df1.shape[1] + df1.shape[1]*2

str1 = t.tabulate(df1.applymap(f'{{:^{width1}}}'.format), list(df1),
                  tablefmt='outline',
                  stralign='center', numalign='center')
str2 = t.tabulate(df2.applymap(f'{{:^{width2}}}'.format), df2.columns,
                  tablefmt='outline',
                  stralign='center', numalign='center')

print(str1 + '\n' + '\n'.join(str2.splitlines()[1:]))
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|    |    Name    |    Age     |   Height   |
+====+============+============+============+
| 0  |   Alice    |     25     |    165     |
| 1  |    Bob     |     30     |    182     |
| 2  |  Charlie   |     35     |    177     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|    |               Summary                |
+====+======================================+
| 0  |        Alice is the youngest         |
| 1  |          Bob is the tallest          |
+----+--------------------------------------+
```

Or to adjust `df2` dynamically from `df1`'s width:

```
import tabulate as t

t.PRESERVE_WHITESPACE = True

str1 = tabulate(df1, list(df1), tablefmt='outline',
                stralign='center', numalign='center')
H = str1.split('\n', 1)[0]
L = len(H)-H[1:].index('+')-5

str2 = tabulate(df2.applymap(f'{{:^{L}}}'.format),
                list(df2), tablefmt='outline',
                stralign='center', numalign='center')

print(str1 + '\n' + '\n'.join(str2.splitlines()[1:]))
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|    |  Name   |  Age  |  Height  |
+====+=========+=======+==========+
| 0  |  Alice  |  25   |   165    |
| 1  |   Bob   |  30   |   182    |
| 2  | Charlie |  35   |   177    |
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|    |          Summary           |
+====+============================+
| 0  |   Alice is the youngest    |
| 1  |     Bob is the tallest     |
+----+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of `.index('+')` is? None of the indices in my two dfs have '+' in the name and calling this line individually yields an error. May you explain further?

Comment: @vicefreak04 this is to get rid of the `+----+---------+-------+----------+` line that would be duplicated since we plot two tables. At this point it has nothing to do with the underlying data, we only have a string representation of the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with pandas. Keep the data in clean DataFrames and then format it when you want them to display somewhere.