# Combine some columns in last row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

*edit:  I understand how to get the actual values, but I wonder how to append a row with these 2 sums to the existing df?*

I have a dataframe score_card that looks like:

| 15min_colour | 15min_high | 15min_price | 30min_colour | 30min_high | 30min_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | -1 | 1 | -1 | 1 |
| 1 | -1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| -1 | 1 | -1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| -1 | 1 | -1 | 1 | -1 | 1 |

Now I'd like to add a row that sums up all the 15min numbers (first 3 columns) and the 30min numbers and so on (the actual df is larger). Means I don't want to add up the individual columns but rather the sum of the columns' sums. The row I'd like to add would look like:

| sum_15min_colour&15min_high&15min_price | sum_30min_colour&30min_high&30min_price |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 8 |

Please disregard the header, it's only to clarify what I'm intending to do.
I assume there's a multiindex involved, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my existing df to achieve the desired output.

Also, is it possible to add a colum with the sum of the whole table?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: The sum of 15 minute groups is zero... amirite

Comment: `np.sum(df.filter(like='15').values)` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum in this way:

```
np.sum(df.filter(like='15').values), np.sum(df.filter(like='30').values)
```

---

```
0,8
```

Comment: Thanks. See edit, how can I append these results to the existing df?

Comment: @Florida_Rolf: How they should look like after getting appended to original dataframe. As you will have 4 columns in original df and this will give you two columns.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to solve. Is there a way of merging 3 columns in the last row?

Comment: @Florida_Rolf: That's actually not possible I guess. You can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533330/pandas-data-frame-how-to-merge-columns

Answer (score 1):

#### `groupby`

Can take a callable (think function) and use it on the `index` or `columns`

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).sum().sum()

15min    0
30min    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. See edit, how can I append these results to the existing df?

Answer (score 0):

- it's depends on axis.

Simply - this sum the value in axis 0:
So in your case - columns(it's sum all values in columns vertically).

```
df.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)
```

---

print(df):

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

```
sum_column = df["col1"] + df["col2"]
df["col3"] = sum_column
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

---

So in your case:

```
summed0Axis = df.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)
sum_column = summed0Axis["15min_colour"] + summed0Axis["15min_high"] + summed0Axis["15min_price"]

print(sum_column)
```

more intelligent option:

Find all columns, which included 15:

```
columnsWith15 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("15").sum]
columnsWith30 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("30").sum]
```